# shorten csv file based on rules python

Tags: python, csv

I am stuck writing the following program.

I have a csv file

```
"SNo","Column1","Column2"
"A1","X","Y"
"A2","A","B"
"A1","X","Z"
"A3","M","N"
"A1","D","E"
```

I want to shorten this csv to follow these rules

```
a.) If the SNo occurs more than once in the file, 
    combine all column1 and column2 entries of that serial number
b.) If same column1 entries and column2 entries occur more than once, 
    then do not combine them twice.
```

Therefore the output of the above should be

```
"SNo","Column1","Column2"
"A1","X,D","Y,Z,E"
"A2","A","B"
"A3","M","N"
```

So far I am reading the csv file, iterating the rows. checking if SNo of next row is same as the previous row. Whats the best way to combine.

```
import csv
temp = "A1"
col1=""
col2=""
col3=""
with open("C:\\file\\file1.csv","rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == temp:
            continue
        col1 = col1+row[1]
        col2=col2+row[2]
        col3=col3+row[3]
        temp = row[0]
        print row[0]+";"+col1+";"+col2+";"+col3
    col1=""
    col2=""
    col3=""
```

Please let me know a good way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You could create a dictionary with `SNo` as key and lists of sets as values, add column1 and 2 to the lists, and then write that back to a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach is to maintain a dictionary with keys as serial numbers and sets to contain the columns.  Then you could do something like the following:

```
my_dict = {}

for row in reader:
    if not row[0] in my_dict.keys():
        my_dict[row[0]] = [set(), set()]

    my_dict[row[0]][0].add(row[1])
    my_dict[row[0]][1].add(row[2])
```

Writing the file out (to a file opened as `file_out`) would be as simple as iterating through the dictionary using a join command:

```
for k in my_dict.keys(): 
    file_out.write("{0},\"{1}\",\"{2}\"\n".format(
        k,
        ','.join([x for x in my_dict[k][0]]),
        ','.join([x for x in my_dict[k][1]])
    ))
```

Comment: A typo :) it's just a file handle for writing out the CSV